# How to configure the time zone in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to configure the date-zone in my rails app, i want that when insert a new record in any table, that the timestamps columns (created_at and updated_at), be saved in my time zone (in my case Bogotá).

I'm writing this in my `application.rb` file:

```
config.time_zone = 'Bogota'
config.active_record.default_timezone = 'Bogota'
```

I'm trying the following too:

```
config.time_zone = 'Bogota'
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local'
```

But it doesn't seems to work

Can someone help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you provide code where you added `config.time_zone = 'Bogota' `?

Comment: as per Tom Connolly's answer, try to restart your rails server.  Every change you do to any file in the config directory needs a server restart.

Answer (score 0):

```
 config.time_zone = 'Bogota' 
 config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
```

is the correct code, in application.rb. Make sure you reboot the server